# Mock navigation service in jest

Tags: javascript, testing, mocking, jestjs, redux-observable

I'm using react-navigation and calling that service in my code. Although I'm not sure how to mock the `navigate` function. Here is my code:

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

let _navigator;

function setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef) {
  _navigator = navigatorRef;
}

function navigate(routeName, params) {
  _navigator.dispatch(
    NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName,
      params,
    })
  );
}

// add other navigation functions that you need and export them

export default {
  navigate,
  setTopLevelNavigator,
};
```

Here is what I got so far:

```
export const loginEpic = (action$, state$, { ajax, navigate }) =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType(LOGIN_REQUEST),
    map(() => state$.value),
    switchMap((options) =>
      ajax(options).pipe(
        pluck("response"),
        map((res) => loginSuccess(res)),
        tap((r) => navigate(ROUTES.DASHBOARD_SCREEN))
      )
    )
  );
```

`navigate` is `navigationService.navigate` and I'm passing it from the dependencies of `redux-observables`.

The test looks like this:

```
const dependencies = {
      ajax: ({ }) => of(mockedResponseFromAjax),
      navigate: () => // ??? 
    };
    const result$ = loginEpic(action$, state$, dependencies).pipe(toArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1: - What worked for me:**

```
import NavigationService from '<your-path>/NavigationService';

beforeEach(() => {
    NavigationService.navigate = jest.fn();
});
```

within my test file.

**Option 2: - Better Version**

see [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55319581/why-isn´t-mock-from-mock-folder-invoked-when-running-test-for-redux-action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55319581/why-isn%C2%B4t-mock-from-mock-folder-invoked-when-running-test-for-redux-action)

it is important that you activate the mock by `jest.mock('../../app/utils/NavigationService');` this has to be placed at the top of your test file directly behind the imports