# Why isn´t mock from __mock__ folder invoked when running test for redux action?

Tags: react-native, mocking, react-redux, jestjs, react-navigation

I call the react-navigation NavigationService within a redux action.
Testing the action I need to mock the navigate function.

`/app/utils/NavigationService.js`

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

let navigator;

function setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef) {
  navigator = navigatorRef;
}

function navigate(routeName, params) {
  navigator.dispatch(NavigationActions.navigate({
    type: NavigationActions.NAVIGATE,
    routeName,
    params,
  }));
}

// add other navigation functions that you need and export them

export default {
  navigate,
  setTopLevelNavigator,
};
```

I created a `__mock__` folder immediately adjacent to the NavigationService.js file.

`app/utils/__mocks__/NavigationService.js` **UPDATED**

```
const navigate = jest.fn();
const setTopLevelNavigator = jest.fn();

export default {
    navigate,
    setTopLevelNavigator,
};
```

Why doesn´t jest auto-mock the `navigate` function when the test is run?
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks

`__tests__/actions/AuthActions.test.js` **UPDATED**

```
jest.mock('../../app/utils/NavigationService'); //at the top directly behind other imports

it('should call firebase on signIn', () => {
    const user = {
      email: 'test@test.com',
      password: 'sign',
    };

    const expected = [
      { type: types.LOGIN_USER },
      { payload: 1, type: types.DB_VERSION },
      { payload: 'prod', type: types.USER_TYPE },
      { payload: { name: 'data' }, type: types.WEEKPLAN_FETCH_SUCCESS },
      { payload: { name: 'data' }, type: types.RECIPELIBRARY_FETCH_SUCCESS },
      {
        payload: { user: { name: 'user' }, userVersionAndType: { dbVersion: 1, userType: 'prod' } },
        type: types.LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS,
      },
    ];

    return store.dispatch(actions.loginUser(user)).then(() => {
      expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expected);
    });
  });
```

`app/actions/AuthActions.js`

```
export const loginUser = ({ email, password }) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({ type: LOGIN_USER });
  return firebase
    .auth()
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .catch((signInError) => {
      dispatch({ type: CREATE_USER, payload: signInError.message });
      return firebase
        .auth()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(async (user) => {
          const userVersionAndType = await dispatch(initUser());
          await dispatch(initWeekplan(userVersionAndType));
          await dispatch(initRecipeLibrary(userVersionAndType));
          return user;
        });
    })
    .then(async (user) => {
      saveCredentials(email, password);
      const userVersionAndType = await dispatch(getUserVersionAndType());
      await dispatch(weekplanFetch(userVersionAndType));
      await dispatch(recipeLibraryFetch(userVersionAndType));
      dispatch(loginUserSuccess({ user, userVersionAndType }));
      NavigationService.navigate('Home');
    })
    .catch(error => dispatch(loginUserFail(error.message)));
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've create a [manual mock for a user module](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-user-modules).

Activating a manual mock of a **user module** for a particular test file requires a call to `jest.mock`.

For this particular case add this line to the top of `__tests__/actions/AuthActions.test.js` and the mock will be used for all tests within that test file:

```
jest.mock('../../app/utils/NavigationService');  // use the manual mock in this test file
```

---

Note that manual mocks for **user modules** and **Node core modules** (like `fs`, `path`, `util`, etc.) both have to be activated for a particular test file by a call to `jest.mock`, and that this behavior is different than manual mocks for **Node modules** which are automatically applied to all tests.

Comment: thanks for your reply. reading the docs again I would've expected it to work. unfortunately it doesn't. See the updated `AuthActions.test.js` Did I do something wrong? the error I get is `Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined`

Comment: I found the problem. https://github.com/reach/router/issues/76#issuecomment-396862351 gave me the missing piece

Comment: I also had to adjust the NavigationService.js see update